# Issue with layout once I enable Site Collection Publishing Feature

Tags: publishing-site, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page

I currently have enabled the MOSS Enterprise publishing infrastructure feature on an existing site collection that was just a collaboration team site without publishing.

When I enable, the horizontal scroll bar is need to see the complete contents that formerly appeared without issue using the collaboration portal without publishing enabled.  When I deactivate the feature we are back to normal.

What is causing my layout to do this?  Do I now have to republish pages?  I do want to go ahead and utilishing the publishing infrastructure going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the page, or the contents of the navigation bar? I know that when you enable the publishing infrastructure, it renames the "home" tab to be the full site title. You can go modify this in the Navigation settings of the site and title it back to "Home" instead if you prefer.

If you are talking about the contents of the page, you may want to check what master page is being applied. This can cause the page elements to shift. I would reset it to the default masterpage and see if this will correct your issue.

Comment: Precisely the issue.  I need to change one of the headers from the nav menu.  However, it is the parent site collection.   I am only able to change the title as you describe but I would like to keep the title of the collection and just modify the top nav bar to say Home.  I can't seem to find that.